# AngularJS: ngOptions gives error when data set received from function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.8 and have the following code:

**View:**

```
<select ng-model="myForm.car" ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in myForm.getCarObjects()" multiple="true">
</select>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.myForm = {};
$scope.myForm.car = ["nissan"];
$scope.myForm.carObjects = [
    {id: "nissan", name: "Nissan"},
    {id: "toyota", name: "Toyota"},
    {id: "maruti", name: "Maruti"}
];

$scope.myForm.getCarObjects = function() {
    return [
        {id: "nissan", name: "Nissan"},
        {id: "toyota", name: "Toyota"},
        {id: "maruti", name: "Maruti"}
    ]
}
```

This gives the following error:

[image: Error]

Everything still works fine. The model bound to the view still gets updated on the change of value in the select list.

The error is gone when I change the function getCarObjects to the following:

```
$scope.myForm.getCarObjects = function() {
    return this.carObjects;
}
```

Can someone please explain why I get the error when the function returns a newly constructed object array?

Comment: that is how work angular :-) when you return new array, angular think that something change, and run digest loop again, and again get new array, and think that somthing change and ....

Comment: also, by link from exception you can get description in angular docs

Comment: @Grundy Thanks for pointing to the docs. The docs say: "Since getUsers() returns a new array, Angular determines that the model is different on each $digest cycle, resulting in the error. The solution is to return the same array object if the elements have not changed". How are there multiple $digest cycles? Also, what do we need to do in case the array elements change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this error, you have to understand the $digest loop. Angular calls all registered $watch functions, compares the returned values with the old values and calls the respective event listeners, if there are any changes. If there are any changes detected in a $digest loop, then angular starts the $digest loop again, because it is possible that a previously called $watch function could have changed a value. This happens as long as there are changes detected or the loop counter reaches 10, then angular gives up.

In your example, while building the options for your select tag, every call to getCarObjects changes the already registered options again and again because you create object after object.

Hope that helps.